# jQuery hover behaves like click in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hover, click

I am trying to listen for hovers using Jquery like this:

```
$(editable).each(function () {
  $(this).hover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass("inspect");
   });
});
```

which doesn't work in Chrome (using v32), but works in Firefox (using v25).

editable = array of HTML elements (not selectors, actual elements);

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/px3XU/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the **mouseenter** event instead?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Yes, i tried. It didn't work. The thing is it works perfectly in firefox but not in chrome. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the browser lost the element reference in the process, try to verify it.

something like this...

```
$(this).hover(
    function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass("inspect");    
    },
    function(e) {
       if(e.relatedTarget){
         // do what you need when mouseleaves here
       }
});
```

you can look at https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/